# Transfer site using backup buddy

Tags: wordpress

How are you? hope you're doing great. Hope you guys can help me. You see i installed a WordPress work space in c9 and now i am finished and i want to transfer it to another location. I am using a plugin called backup buddy to transfer all the files in the new site but when i open the backup downloaded by the plugin, as you can see on the image below there are 2 folders named .c9 and WordPress. i was just wondering if i can delete those two and what are those 2 folders contain?

thank you guys in advance. :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't edit anything in backupbuddy archive. You gonna make things worse.

If you really need custom file selection, do it in backupbuddy admin panel before taking backup. Messing with zip file gonna corrupt it for sure because those files are logged in backupbuddy log file as well as they gonna have their respective databases. All messed up so better be on safe side.